# How to SUM two first character in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to SUM only first two characters using `SUBSTR` and `GROUP BY` in MySQL?
Such as :

```
SELECT SUM(Substr(period, 1,2) FROM table GROUP BY period
```

I have tried these SQL. But didn't effect because of using `GROUP BY`. The result of these query is sum all of the period value.

Comment: Show your input and desired output..

Comment: What possibly is the purpose of this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (If you want to sum two first characters):

```
SELECT
    SUM(CAST(Substr(period, 1, 1)) AS int) + CAST(Substr(period, 2, 1)) AS int))
FROM
    table
GROUP BY
    period
```

or

```
SELECT
    SUM(CAST(Substr(Period, 1, 2) AS int)) 
FROM
    table
GROUP BY
    period
```

Comment: what the diffrent between UNSIGNED INTEGER and INT? i have put your query but getting error, i replace 'AS Int' with AS UNSIGNED INTEGER, it's work. But the result sum all of value.

Comment: Is there any difference between `sum all of the period value` and `sum all of values`?

Comment: No. it's same. I think it's because of GROUP BY to select distinct period.

Comment: I can't imagine what exactly you want but current query will multiply value of two first characters to count of each period!? is that what you want?

Comment: Actually all of the answer are correct, but something there is something wrong with my data. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ASCII` values of characters instead:

```
SELECT
    ASCII(Substr(period, 1,1)) + ASCII(Substr(period, 2, 1))
FROM
    test group by period;
```